# How to copy IAM setting to a new account with export/import command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'll like to import my existing IAM settings (Users, Groups, Policies, etc..) to a new AWS account, which I've created.

I've tried to use the `GetAccountAuthorizationDetails` API with `aws iam get-account-authorization-details > export_IAM.json` command.

Now, IDK how to export this .json file to my new account.

I'll appreciate it if someone could tell me what the best way to do that, please is.

Comment: Hi @MW1991 did you ever solve this??